# Why is MySQL using filesort in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newsletters` 
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `last_update` int(11) default NULL,
    `status` int(11) default '0',
    `message_id` varchar(255) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
    KEY `status` (`status`),
    KEY `message_id` (`message_id`),
    KEY `last_update` (`last_update`)
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**The Query:**

```
SELECT id, last_update
FROM newsletters
WHERE status = 1
ORDER BY last_update DESC 
LIMIT 0, 100
```

- `newsletters` table has over *3 million records*
- query takes over *26 seconds* to execute

**Query explain:**

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  newsletters range   status  status  5   NULL    3043354 Using where; Using filesort
```

So why is it not using `filesort`, and how is it a `range` query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's using `filesort` to sort on `last_update`.  You can avoid the filesort that by changing the index to `status, last_update`, so MySQL finds all rows with status 1 in the right order.

To further optimize, change the index to `status, last_update, id`.  That allows MySQL to satisfy the query just by looking at the index, without a table lookup.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_newsletters_status
ON newsletters(status, last_update, id);
```

Comment: KEY should apply the indexes the same as INDEX.

Comment: That did it, I am an amateur at optimizing / indexing, so I didn't really think about attempting to index multiple columns. @Baez: Can you please what you mean by that?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: In order to visualize what index would most help you, try to think of what list, in what order would most help _you_ if you were the computer, and had to quickly find the correct records, and return the asked for information. In this case, you would want a list of all the records (since every index needs to be of all the records) sorted first by status (since you are only interested in the 1s), and then by last_update (so that you can quickly get the first 100 of those). If you add the id to the list, then you can get all your information without having to go back to the main table.

Comment: That's a very intuitive way of explaining it. So basically, I should add the indexes in the order that will eliminate the most rows from left to right, correct?